# failed to networkx: SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument

Tags: python

```
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


G = nx.DiGraph()

for d in pd.read_csv("politwi.csv",sep='\s+',"shift-jis", header=None, 
names=['A', 'B'], chunksize=10000,):
    G.add_edges_from([tuple(x) for x in d.values])

for e in G.edges():
    print 



pos = nx.spring_layout(G,scale=1)
nx.draw(G,pos, with_labels=True)
plt.savefig('this.png')
plt.show() 


errorcode:
File "<ipython-input-21-4a0f4e4a5667>", line 8
    for d in pd.read_csv("politwi.csv",sep='\s+',"shift-jis", header=None, 
names=['A', 'B'], chunksize=10000,):
                                            ^
this is my code I try to above,
```

1. this is the code I tried above, but below is the errors

   SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument
2. first i tried to collect tweet from twitter and write it into csv 
   by using this csv, designing wordcloud and networkx. but i failed to make the networkx

my question is
what kind of error? and how to slove it?
i am learning python by myself.
I might not have some important resource about python
so please tell me in detail answer as much as you can

Comment: `chunksize=10000,):` is the *comma* (`,`) intended?

Answer (score 0):

here you have a comma `sep='\s+',"shift-jis"`, between `'\s+'` and `"shift-jis"` it it need to be together remove the comma, but if `"shift-jis"` is a separate argument put in before `sep='\s+'` , also remove comma after `chunksize=10000`